# Getting an image to move freely around the screen

Tags: android, android-canvas

I had a question regarding Android programming. I have created an application to take in data via Bluetooth and I would like to use that input as sort of a "game controller" to move an image around a screen. For instance, if the "up" command was given, the image (or even a colored circle) would move a few pixels up.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I thought of using a canvas and redrawing the image every so often but I don't know how to do this and I thought there might be a better/simpler way. I don't need anything fancy.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do. Catch the up command, then have a class lets call it Circle which will hold the current circles position, size etc.
Whenever you catch the up command or left or right or any kind of command, you would redraw the image in that position. I would also use a custom surface view for the drawing and an Activity for catching all the inputs and passing them onto the object.
I would check out 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-moving-images.html

and read through the whole series, if you have the time. It is quite a good read.